# [JAVA]Alternatives to ZipInputStream thread safe

Tags: java, thread-safety, zip, zipinputstream

I have some concurrency problems with `ZipInputStream` and I found that it is not safe thread. Do you know any alternative which is threaded safe?

Thank you

Comment: I'm struggling to think of a scenario where you would have to write to a zip file concurrently from multiple threads.

Comment: *All* streams are thread-unsafe in this sense. Use a separate one per thread, or sequentialize your code.

Answer (score 0):

Well You will search for everyplace for a Thread Safe for a ZipInputStream. But the downside of this that none of the [InputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html) implementations in Java are thread-safe. The only way of doing this is Synch your code for only a Thread access the file that you want.